# Can the Nine-Tails now leave Naruto's body at will?

Tags: naruto

After Naruto and the Nine-Tails became friends, Naruto unlocked the seal.  Does that mean that the Nine-Tails can escape out of Naruto at his will whenever he wants?  If so, why doesn't he do so?  After helping him, couldn't they both go their separate ways?  If he were to leave, would Naruto die?

And while fighting Tobi in tailed beast mode, Naruto's seal was unlocked. Couldn't Tobi have used his Sharingan to control the Nine-Tails and force him out of Naruto, just like he did with Kushina when the seal was weakened during childbirth?

Comment: Both too broad and marginally opinion based as well. I would recommend you to go through here, http://anime.stackexchange.com/help
It would help you ask better questions. Such broad questions are better left to other forums, discussion groups or our Chat. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697

Comment: @Arcane: I feel like with a little bit of editing, this question could be made more on-topic...

Answer (score 6):

The short answer:

## No, the Nine-Tails could not leave Naruto's body at will.

The longer answer:

Bijuu remain sealed inside of a jinchuuriki [until either](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Jinchuuriki#Sealing):

- the host loses control of the bijuu inside,
- the seal weakens, or
- it is forcefully extracted.

In the event that the bijuu is extracted, **the original host *typically* dies.**  The Uzumaki clan has had a few temporal survivors of a forceful Bijuu extraction.

The specific example you reference for the Nine-Tails to be taken out of Naruto only really applies to female jinchuuriki; the seal is weakest during childbirth, and given that Tobi had attacked Kushina and Minato while Naruto was being born, extracting the Nine-Tails wasn't a difficult task.

Bear in mind that the seal between Naruto and the Nine-Tails really represented an ideological and metaphysical seal.  The seal prevented the Nine-Tails from *fully* taking control of Naruto's body and will, and also prevented Naruto from fully influencing the Nine-Tails.  However, after he had befriended Kurama and established mutual respect between them, the seal was no longer necessary.

Comment: oh!! So the seal is not for keeping nine tails inside Naruto but its for keeping nine tails from taking over Naruto!! When the seal weakens, nine tail's will can seep through with his chakra and take over Naruto!! To extract nine tails you have to use external methods!! And once nine tails and Naruto were friends, they didnt have to fight for control anymore so they opened the seal!! Am I right??

Comment: @MartianCactus:  The seal does very much also exist to keep the Nine-Tails inside of Naruto.  It just works both ways; it keeps the beast inside but also prevented the beast from taking over his will.

Comment: so when they werent friends, nine tails wanted Naruto to lose control so that he can escape!!

Comment: ...or take over his body, that sort of ideal.  It's why the seal is so symbolic throughout the *entire* series, and the reason that they're able to be equal partners now is *such* a big deal.

Comment: oh!! But this still doesnt explain why when they were frienda and the seal was unlocked, Tobi didnt use sharingan genjutsu to force out the nine tails

Comment: and so once they are friends and the seal isnt there, can nine tails escape at will or does it still have to be extracted to get out?

Comment: @MartianCactus:  I believe I've already adequately answered your question in the answer.

Comment: No I don’t think you’ve adequately answered the question. The bijuu can leave if the seal is weakened. There is no more seal so why wouldn’t it be possible?